# how to have Asterisk-AGI like functionality in OpenSIPs or Kamailio

Tags: asterisk, agi, kamailio, opensips

I used to send AGI requests from Asterisk SIP server to an external App and reply back with commands like DIAL(...). I'm trying to do the same in opensips using Events Interface (UDP), Management Interface (UDP too) and the dialog module. Any advice is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use lua or perl module.

Or use perl to emulate AGI interface.

But that is anyway bad idea. Becuase opensips is proxy, it require understand of sip protocol,not only dial.

So looks like you need expert who will create config for opensips for your task(contol via external app).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I think that I will use the rest_client module to have interaction with the external app. I'll give it a try